# Visual Studio Code Ubuntu aspnet core 2 container debugging

Tags: ubuntu, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.0

I googled and looked on stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution.

## Setup:

Host OS: Ubuntu

ASPNet Core 2

Dotnet 2.0

---

I have two containers, one container for MySQL and other for dotnet core. I was able to run it without installing CLR Debugger. After installing CLR debugger in one container, I am trying to use Visual Studio Code to debug aspnet core 2 app running in that container. I am getting following error:

"The pipe program 'bash' exited unexpectedly."

Only option is to "open Launch.json" and only bash command in launch.json is:

```
        "pipeTransport": {            
            "pipeProgram": "/bin/bash",            
            "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",            
            "pipeArgs": ["-c",            
                "docker exec -i devexamapp_debug_1 /clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi"],
            "debuggerPath": "/vsdbg/vsdbg"
```

Debug console shows following:

Starting: "/bin/bash" -c "docker exec -i devexamapp_debug_1 /clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi" "/vsdbg/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode"

If I run "/bin/bash" -c "docker exec -i devexamapp_debug_1 /clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi" "/vsdbg/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode" in a console window then it works 100% fine withotu any error.

What am I missing? Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Probably it is running some wrong command,  with total combination. See if you could figure what command was actually run?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Only thing I can check from Visual Studio Code is what it prints in "Debug Console" at bottom. 

Is there a way to check what is it running? Some log or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit-1: 14-Oct**

You need to have the debugger installed in your Docker image. You can do the same by adding below to your dockerfile

```
WORKDIR /vsdbg 
RUN curl -SL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg
```

Then you need to updated the `pipeTransport` in `launch.json` as below

```
"pipeTransport": { 
   "pipeProgram": "docker", 
   "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}", 
   "pipeArgs": ["exec -i devexamapp_debug_1"], 
   "debuggerPath": "/vsdbg/vsdbg", 
   "quoteArgs": false 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I get following error now:

**Starting: "docker" exec -i devexamapp_debug_1 /clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi /vsdbg/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode

Error from pipe program 'docker': ERROR: Unknown argument '/vsdbg/vsdbg'.** 

I tried to remove "debuggerPath" but that didn't work either. It says "debuggerPath" is required.

Comment: Please join this chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156714/visual-studio-code-ubuntu-aspnet-core-2-container-debugging

Comment: It won't allow me to post any message in chat room, stackoverflow requires 20 reputation points or something.

Comment: Try changing `"debuggerPath": "/vsdbg/vsdbg"` to `"debuggerPath": "/clrdbg/clrdbg"` and see if it helps? also try using you original approach with `"quoteArgs": false` added and see if that helps?

Comment: First tried **"pipeArgs": ["exec -i devexamapp_debug_1 /clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi"],"debuggerPath": "/clrdbg/clrdbg"** - error was "This version of the C# extension no longer supports connecting to clrdbg and install vsdbg". Tried original with `"quoteArgs":false` and error was: _error from pipe program, docker command has wrong usage_

Comment: Finally made it work, with hints from your comments and trying different approaches. `WORKDIR /vsdbg
RUN curl -SL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg` added in Docker file for image. And then used following for pipe **"pipeTransport": {            
                "pipeProgram": "docker",            
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",            
                "pipeArgs": ["exec -i devexamapp_debug_1"],
                "debuggerPath": "/vsdbg/vsdbg",
                "quoteArgs": false            
            }**

Comment: I will let you update your answer, I marked your answer as final solution so keeping final solution in there will help anyone else looking to solve it for aspnet core 2.0. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @SharpCoder, check if the updates are correct and let me know if I missed anything